# Math symbols are not loading

Tags: math-mode

In my document, I am trying to get some math symbols to load, but it is not doing so. Here is a line of code I'm having trouble with, for example.

```
\item Know (or be able to compute by hand) the values resulting
 from inputting $\frac{k\pi}{12}, \, k \in \Z$ into the $/sin , 
/cos , /tan , /sec , /csc , /cot , /cis$ functions.
```

However, this is the result I am getting. Notice how the well-known integer set is missing, the trig functions are not configuring, and the 'element' symbol looks kind of weird.

[image]

In the preamble, I included the packages I want to use. These are the ones I have: `{ifthen,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,bm,graphicx,color}`. I have been able to get the symbols to show in every single document I've made, but don't know what I'm doing wrong right now...

Comment: It should be `\sin` instead of `/sin`, and so on.

Comment: About missing `\Z`: never ignore the log output with error messages. Error message says what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the backslash consistently. Also `\Z` and `\cis` are not predefined and you need to define them.

Also be aware that a list of formulas is not a single formula. So you should separate the two parts of the initial formulas into two distinct ones. Feeling the need of `\,` after a comma is a clear sign that you should consider *two* formulas instead of one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\DeclareMathOperator{\cis}{cis}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item Know (or be able to compute by hand) the values resulting from
  inputting $\frac{k\pi}{12}$, $k \in \Z$, into the $\sin$, $\cos$,
  $\tan$, $\sec$, $\csc$, $\cot$, $\cis$ functions.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It fixed my problems.

Answer (score 1):

Please use `\` instead of `/`

```
\item Know (or be able to compute by hand) the values resulting from inputting $\frac{k\pi}{12}, \, k \in \mathbb{Z}$ into the $\sin , \cos , \tan , \sec , \csc , \cot$ functions.
```

[image]

Comment: Oh my goodness thank you! I knew it was something silly haha. However, the set "Z" still does not appear.

Comment: @JuneRichardson How are you defining `\Z`? Could you show us a MWE that includes the whole preamble and this bit of text?

Comment: It looks like you want `\Z` to be defined as `\mathbb{Z}`, and the command must exist or you’d be getting a compile error, but be set to something else.

Comment: That or your `\mathbb` alphabet isn’t set up right, somehow. You did say you included `amssymb`, which should work.